# If $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_k=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I am dealing with the test of the OBM (Brasilian Math Olympiad), University level, 2016, phase 2.

As I've said at [this topic (question 2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981087/find-all-functions-such-that-fx2y2fx-xfy2-fx2), I hope someone can help me to discuss this test. Thanks for any help.

The question 1 says:

> Let be $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ a real sequence such that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{a_n}{n}$ converges. Prove that:
>
> ### $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_k=0$.

My attempt:

I've had an ideia if the sequence is positive. Something like that:

Let be $C=\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{a_n}{n}$. The terms of the sum that we'll lead are nearlier of $0$ than these terms, so the limit exists. ***(Do I need anything else here?)***

Take $n=2^m$. We have $\dfrac{a_i}{n}\leq\dfrac{a_i}{i}-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{a_i}{i}-\ldots - \dfrac{1}{2^j}\dfrac{a_i}{i}$ if $\dfrac{1}{n}\leq \dfrac{1}{i}\bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{2}-\ldots - \dfrac{1}{2^j}\bigg)$, it means, $i\leq n\dfrac{1}{2^j}$. So,

$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_k=$
$\dfrac{a_{2^m}}{2^m}+\dfrac{a_{2^m-1}}{2^m}+\ldots + \dfrac{a_1}{2^m}\leq$
$\sum_{k=1}^{2^m}a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{2^{m-1}}a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{2^{m-2}}a_k-\ldots -\sum_{k=1}^{2^0}a_k$

Carrying to infty,

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_k\leq C-\dfrac{1}{2}C-\dfrac{1}{4}C-\ldots=0$

As the terms are positive, the limit is zero, as we need prove.

How can I extend if there's negative terms?

I know there are gaps on my thoughts. I thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac  {a_k} k$. Then $a_n=n(s_n-s_{n-1})$. Hence $\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k=\frac 1 n (-s_1-s_2-\cdots-s_{n-1}+ns_n)$ (after some simplification). Now use the fact that $s_n \to s$ implies $\frac 1 {n-1} (-s_1-s_2-\cdots-s_{n-1}) \to -s$ and $\frac n {n-1} \to 1$.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your answer is very clear ... congratulations!!

Answer (score 6):

Let $s_0=0$ and for $n\geq 1$,
$$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k}k$$
Then if $k\geq 1$, $a_k=k(s_k-s_{k-1})$

We have 
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} k(s_k-s_{k-1})\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} ks_k-  \sum_{k=1}^{n}ks_{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} ks_k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+1)s_k\\
&= ns_n -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k
\end{split}$$
In other words
$$\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k = s_n -   \frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k$$
Since by assumption, $s_n$ converges to a limit (let's call it $s$), by [Cesaro's summation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation), so does $\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k$.
It follows that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k =s-s=0$$

Comment: I did not know this Theorem, Stefan, and your link helped a lot. I thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: (+1) Nicely written.

Comment: Why there are $n-1$ partial sums instead of $n$ as it's written at the page you sent?

Comment: $\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k=-\frac{s_n}n + \frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k$ , and $\frac{s_n}n\rightarrow 0$, so it doesn't matter if the sum goes to $n$ or $n-1$. the