# A prime divisor in a second order recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations, contest-math

I am dealing with the test of the OBM (Brasilian Math Olympiad), University level, 2016, phase 2.

As I've said at [this topic (question 1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981087/find-all-functions-such-that-fx2y2fx-xfy2-fx2/2987976#2987976), this [other (question 2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981087/find-all-functions-such-that-fx2y2fx-xfy2-fx2) and [this (question 3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991979/matrix-with-integer-coordinates), I hope someone can help me to discuss this test. Thanks for any help.

The question 3 says:

> Let $k\geq 1$ be an integer. We define the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ by $a_0=0,a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=ka_n+a_{n-1}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$.
>
> Let $p$ be a prime odd number. Call $m(p)$ the smallest positive integer $i$ such that $p\mid a_i$.
>
> Call $T(p)$ the smallest positive integer such that for all $j$ we have $p\mid a_{j+T(p)}-a_j$.
>
> (i) Show that $T(p)\leq m(p)(p-1)$.
>
> (ii) If $T(p)=m(p)(p-1)$, show that $\prod_{{1\leq j\leq T(p)-1}_{j\neq0\pmod {m(p)}}}a_j\equiv (-1)^{m(p)-1}\pmod p$.

I've tried somethings, but don't get anything substantial. I'd like to have clues to this type of problem... In fact, I couldn't at least prove that $m(p)$ always exists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us fix an odd prime $\require{cancel}p$, and let $\bar{a}_n$ be the reduction of $a_n$ modulo $p$, i.e., as members of $\mathbb{Z}/p=\mathbb{F}_p$.  There is a standard trick of letting
$$
\mathbf{b}_n=\begin{bmatrix}\bar{a}_{n+1}\\\bar{a}_n\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{F}_p^2,
$$
which converts the second order difference equation into a first-order difference equation (at the cost of having a vector equation rather than a scalar one):
$$
\mathbf{b}_{n+1}=T\,\mathbf{b}_n,\quad T:=\begin{bmatrix}k&1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\quad
\mathbf{b}_0=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So $\mathbf{b}_{n+1}$ depends only on $\mathbf{b}_n$.  Note that $\det T=-1$ so $T^{-1}$ exists.

By pigeonhole, there exists $0\leq i<j\leq p^2$ such that $\mathbf{b}_i=\mathbf{b}_j$.  Applying $T^{-i}$, you get $\mathbf{b}_{j-i}=\mathbf{b}_0$, and applying $T^n$ gives $\mathbf{b}_{n+j-i}=\mathbf{b}_n$ for all $n$.
So $T(p)$ exists and is equal to the minimal period of $(\mathbf{b}_n)_{n\geq 0}$.  (This implies existence of $m(p)$, which is clearly $\leq T(p)$ by putting $j=0$ in the definition.)

For (i):

> we consider what $\mathbf{b}_{m(p)},\mathbf{b}_{2m(p)},\mathbf{b}_{3m(p)},\dots$ could be.
>  The last coordinate must be $0$, but the first coordinate isn't fixed.

However, we know

> **Claim:** $$a_{km(p)+1}\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$
>  *Proof.*
>  If $a_{km(p)+1}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then $\mathbf{b}_{km(p)}=\mathbf{0}$.
>  Applying $T^{-km(p)}$ gives $\mathbf{b}_0=\mathbf{0}$, contradiction. $\square$

We have:

> $T^{m(p)}\mathbf{b}_0=\bar{a}_{m(p)+1}\mathbf{b}_0$, so
>  $$T^{m(p)(p-1)}\mathbf{b}_0=(\bar{a}_{m(p)+1})^{p-1}\mathbf{b}_0=\mathbf{b}_0$$
>  by Fermat's little theorem, and hence $T(p)\leq m(p)(p-1)$.

For (ii):

> If $T(p)=m(p)(p-1)$, then $(\bar{a}_{m(p)+1})^j$ for $j=1,2,\dots,p-1$ are all distinct, i.e., $\mu=\bar{a}_{m(p)+1}$ is a generator of $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$.  We have $\{\mu,\mu^2,\dots,\mu^{p-1}\}=\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$ and so applying Wilson's theorem gives $\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}\mu^k=(p-1)!=-1$.

Hence

> \begin{align}\prod_{\substack{1\leq j\leq T(p)-1\\m(p)\nmid j}}\bar{a}_j &=\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}\prod_{j=1}^{m(p)-1}\bar{a}_{km(p)+j}\\ &=\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}\prod_{j=1}^{m(p)-1}(\mu^k\bar{a}_j)\\ &=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}\prod_{j=1}^{m(p)-1}\mu^k\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}\prod_{j=1}^{m(p)-1}\bar{a}_j\right)\\ &=\left[\prod_{j=1}^{m(p)-1}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}\mu^k\right)\right]\cancelto{1}{\color{red}{\left(\prod_{j=1}^{m(p)-1}\bar{a}_j\right)^{p-1}}}\\ &=(-1)^{m(p)-1} \end{align}

as claimed.

Comment: I thank you very much once again! The trick was very important. I'd like to congratulate you for those answer.