# Matrix with integer coordinates

Tags: recurrence-relations, contest-math, matrix-equations

I am dealing with the test of the OBM (Brasilian Math Olympiad), University level, 2016, phase 2.

As I've said at [this topic (question 1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981087/find-all-functions-such-that-fx2y2fx-xfy2-fx2/2987976#2987976), this [other (question 2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981087/find-all-functions-such-that-fx2y2fx-xfy2-fx2) and [this (question 3, yet open)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991694/a-prime-divisor-in-a-second-order-recurrence), I hope someone can help me to discuss this test. Thanks for any help.

The question 4 says:

> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}4&-\sqrt5\\ 2\sqrt5&-3\end{pmatrix}$.
>
> Find all the pairs of numbers $(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}$ with $|m|\leq n$ such that $A^n-(n^2+m)A$ has all the coordinates integers.

I'm trying solving this and I'd like a lot to have clues.

I'm doing some "simulations" and have an ideia about $a_{n21}$ (entry $21$ of the matrix $A^n$). It seems $x_n\sqrt{5}$ where $x_n=2$ to $n=1,2$ and $x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}+2x_n$. Maybe we can use something about recurrence. I'm trying.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe rewriting to $(A^{n-1} - (n^2+m)I)A$ could help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pure computation.

$A$ has characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(t)=t^2-t-2$, so has eigenvalues $2,-1$.  By Cayley-Hamilton, $\chi_A(A)=0$ and so
$$
A^{n+2}=A^{n+1}+2A^n.
$$
Hence the diagonals are integers for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Also, we have an explicit formula for $A^n$:

> $$A^n=\frac13\begin{pmatrix}(-2)(-1)^n+5\times 2^n & -(2^n-(-1)^n)\sqrt{5}\\2(2^n-(-1)^n)\sqrt{5} & 5(-1)^n-2^{n+1}\end{pmatrix}.$$
> This is easily obtained from fitting the coefficients for $A^0=I$ and $A^1=A$.

The upshot is that we want

> $$m=\frac{2^n-(-1)^n}3-n^2$$

for which there are only finitely many solution $\lvert m\rvert\leq n$:

> since $2^n$ eventually dominates in the RHS.

It is easy enough to estimate when to stop looking:

> if $2^n>6n^2$ then $2^n>3(n^2+n)$ so $m>n$.  So we only need to compute up to $n\leq 7$.

The result is:

> \begin{array}{c|c|c}n & m & \text{Solution?}\\\hline0 & 0 & \text{Yes}\\1 & 0 & \text{Yes}\\2 & -3 & \text{No}\\3 & -6 & \text{No}\\4 & -11 & \text{No}\\5 & -14 & \text{No}\\6 & -15 & \text{No}\\7 & -6 & \text{Yes}\end{array}

The examiner seems to have a sense of humour:  Note that the only nontrivial solution gives $A^n-(n^2+m)A=42I$, so maybe this is motivated by the *"Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything"* in *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*?

Comment: When to use the fact of recurrence?

Comment: How did you get the upshot?

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo 1) To determine $A^n$, eg read the first hidden block. 2) To make the upper right entry an integer. IE determine $ A^n +(n^2+m) A$.

Comment: It would be better to explicit answer the question with this observation.

Answer (score 0):

*Observation:* in the answer above, note that $A = S\Lambda S^{-1}$ (this implies $A^n = S\Lambda^n S^{-1}$), since A is diagonalizable matrix. Now, since the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = -1$ and $\lambda_2 = 2$ (note that we decided to choose this order), we have that:

$$\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\ 0&\lambda_2\end{pmatrix}$$

Now observe that it can be proven that:

$$\Lambda^n=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1^n&0\\ 0&\lambda_2^n\end{pmatrix}$$

So it follows:

$$\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}(-1)^n&0\\ 0&2^n\end{pmatrix}$$

$S$ is given by the matrix the "composition" of the eigenvectors, corresponding respectively to $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Supose $v_1$ and $v_2$, they are given by the column vectors:

$$v_1 = (1, \sqrt 5 ) $$ and $$v_2 = (\sqrt 5, 1) $$

So, we have that:

$$S=\begin{pmatrix}1&\sqrt5\\ \sqrt5&1\end{pmatrix}$$

And the inverse can be found easily.