# Beautiful real functions ($f\in C^2; C,D>0 : |x^3f(x)|\leq C$ and $|xf''(x)|\leq D$ for all $x:|x|\geq1$)

Tags: functions, derivatives, contest-math

I am dealing with the test of the OBM (Brasilian Math Olympiad), University level, 2016, phase 2.

As I've said at [this topic (question 1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981087/find-all-functions-such-that-fx2y2fx-xfy2-fx2/2987976#2987976), this [other (question 2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981087/find-all-functions-such-that-fx2y2fx-xfy2-fx2) and [this (question 3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991694/a-prime-divisor-in-a-second-order-recurrence), [this (question 5)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2995315/finding-all-soccer-polyhedra-each-vertex-meets-three-faces-two-m-gons-and/2995344?noredirect=1#comment6179991_2995344) and [this (question 4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991979/matrix-with-integer-coordinates/2992021#2992021), I hope someone can help me to discuss this test. Thanks for any help.

The question 6 says:

> Let $C, D>0$. We say a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is beautiful if $f\in C^2$, $|x^3f(x)|\leq C$ and $|xf''(x)|\leq D$ for all $x$ with $|x|\geq1$.
>
> (i) Prove that if $f$ is beautiful, given $\epsilon >0$, there's $x_0>0$ such that, for $|x|\geq x_0$, $|x^2f'(x)|<\sqrt{2CD}+\epsilon$.
>
> (ii) Prove that, if $0<E<\sqrt{2CD}$, then exists a beautiful function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that, for all $x_0>0$, there's $x>x_0$ with $|x^2f'(x)|>E$.

I think there's something with Taylor's formula. I know also that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f''(x)=0$... Right?

A important result is:
**"If $f$ is derivative in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'$ is limited, so $f$ is lipschtiz."**

Therefore, $f|_{\mathbb{R}-[-1,1]},f'|_{\mathbb{R}-[-1,1]}$ are lipschtiz.

More than an answer, I'd like to get some clues too. In general, I cannot know the way and results I should take. Should I take any way and try, try, try? What did you do when take a dificult question?

Thank you for a help and a blessed day.

Comment: Yes, you can use some Taylor-type expansion (or integration).  If you have seen the version without $x$ factors in front and over all $\mathbb{R}$, i,e, $\lVert u'\rVert\leq\sqrt{\lVert u\rVert\cdot\lVert u''\rVert}$ if $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ bounded), try adapting that proof to this case.

Comment: Sorry because I didn't return, I was desconected of these questions for some days. Now, I'll try do what you've said. Thank you.